# How can I connect two offices to each other?

Tags: networking

If I want to connect two offices physically separate from each other but in the same city, what type of features do I need?

I want to allow the following;

1. allow users to log in using accounts
2. allow users to log in from home
3. have printers attached to the network
4. allow users to save files in their account ?file server?
5. perhaps a database is needed, not sure why yet
6. allow users to send emails
7. allow users to telephone calls,voip? any other method?

Some features of the network, each site has at least 15 pc's and 3 multi-function network printers.

I was thinking of the following;

Servers: Mail, Web, File, print, directory, database, VPN
Other: Switch, firewall, router, cat5e cabling, network printers, telephones.

I am not sure if this can be done, but since web and mail requires little bandwidth then only have mail and web server in one location? Can I even merge the two in one server instead of having separate servers for each, and if this is done which of the above servers should be merged into one big server, perhaps (mail, web, file, print) can these coexist in one powerful server? or is not recommended?

This is my proposed network for the main branch

[image: Proposal]

This is for an assignment I need to do but I have never done any networking so I am a bit lost, I have spent 2 days trying to gather as much information as possible.

Comment: why did i get a vote down, ive spent 2 days researching

Comment: *Six* 2U servers at a location with "at least 15 PCs" seems like a bit much; surely most of those boxes would be at least 95% idle, at least 95% of the time. There is value in separating roles but servers can be virtualized.

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos My guess is because your question reads a little like homework: The problem you're asking to solve is pretty trivial for experienced admins, and if you're feeling out of your depth implementing it the answer is likely to be "Get some help from an experienced professional before you accidentally break something"

Comment: I agree with the overuse of servers. To be honest, one SBS server with 16GB of RAM or so would be sufficient to serve 15 clients efficiently.

Comment: From what i had read i can merge (mail,web) in one server since they dont need alot of bandwith, can you guys help me then merge the others,

Comment: File, Directory, Domain, and Mail can all be on the same server. Web and VPN can be consolidated as well. 2 servers, maximum. One for hosting your internal services, one for hosting things that must be internet-facing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you need is a VPN between to the locations. If properly configured, all resources from one side should be available to users on the other side, and vise versa.

I recommend [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/overview.html), but if you have Windows servers, you can use the [Windows RRAS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb545655) (Router and Remote Access services)

What I would do in your situation is:

1. A 'main' office, with better hardware, hosting the Domain Controller, and other network services.
2. A 'branch' office, with a second domain controller (RODC's are good in this use case) and other network services.
3. DIFFERENT SUBNETS FOR EACH LOCATION. If Network A(main) is 10.0.0.0/24, make Network B(branch) be 10.0.1.0/24.
4. A VPN solution to connect the two networks

Comment: I'd agree with this. This might very well be all that you need, and if it isn't, its still the first building block upon which extras would need to be built. Once the offices can communicate, you can then test to see if performance of all the functions you want is adequate over the link, and if not you can then spend more time and money on those specific areas, which is much better than taking a scatter-gun approach of trying to do everything.

Comment: As long as the routing between the two locations is good, it should be all he needs.

Comment: What about the servers, do i need file serves on both same as vpn servers on both, how about to allow the employees to connect to their accounts

Comment: Is this network all imaginary at this point? If you have two fully functioning locations, complete with two separate domains, you'll need: a)VPN to connect the two sites, b) a TRUST established between the two domains to allow users from one to access resources on another.

Comment: Right now i am doing it in Visio, its an imaginary network, its for an assignment i have in college

Comment: Let me reiterate: The VPN is used SOLELY to connect the two network (Virtual Private Network). If you're designing this network from the ground-up, you'll need a few different concepts. I'll expand in the answer.

Comment: Well the assignment required me to create an scenario where a small company had a bad network and i as the consultant is to upgrade it and also connect it to the other new branch.

Comment: Okay, so the branch office DOESNT exist yet in your scenario? Then you'll just modify the order a little bit. You'll want to establish the VPN to the second location FIRST, and then after you do that you can create the secondary domain controller and other resources.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3204/discussion-between-johnthepro-and-jose-david-garcia-llanos)

Comment: @JohnThePro - I agree that the link should be all he needs, hence the upvote, but in practice (and therefore maybe worth mentioning in the assignment) it may be that the quality or capacity of the links is such that some things are best provided by local servers with replication between them (e.g. file services, especially for home drives) rather than over the link. This is why I said you'd establish the link first and see if that was enough, then look at any problematic services in detail.

Comment: this is my proposed network for the main branch http://i40.tinypic.com/slkydl.jpg

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos - the workstation LAN connects to the switch, not directly to the servers (unless you mean there are two switches present, in which case you need to add the second one). The core/main switch on a network is like a spider sitting at the centre of the web.

Comment: Then you need to change your diagram :-)

Comment: done, its changed :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3206/discussion-between-jose-david-garcia-llanos-and-dj-pon3)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3210/discussion-between-jose-david-garcia-llanos-and-dj-pon3)